# Como saber en que página de mi web me encuentro y darle un estilo diferente a ese enlace en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

tengo una barra de navegacion nav-bar en Angular, le llamo por un component aparte y lo que necesito es que cuando muestro esta barra de navegación me muestre en que link de mi web estoy, algo como el efecto active de Bootstrap, que toca hacerlo página por página, no hay método en javascript que me solucione este inconveniente o un método en typescript que me funcione para lo mismo.

intente usar un windows.location pero no me ha funcionado.

este es el codigo que he intentado usar para tal fin:

```
    <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened" (opened)="events.push('open!')"
  (closed)="events.push('close!')" class="sidenav"
                 [fixedInViewport]="true" (click)="close('toggle button')">     
        <mat-drawer class="container-dibujo" mode="side" opened>
          <div class="logo-cos">
            <img src="#" alt="logo">
          </div>
          <ul class="content-sidenav-lg">
            <li>
            <a id='pagos' [routerLink]="'/dashboard'"><i class="fi-rr-dollar"></i> Pagos</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
            <a id="certificados" [routerLink]="'/certificados'"><i class="fi-rr-diploma"></i> certificados</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
            <a id="formularios" [routerLink]="'/formularios'"><i class="fi-rr-form"></i> Formularios</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
            <div class="logout">
              <a [routerLink]="'/login'"><i class="fi-rr-sign-out"></i> Cerrar sesión</a>
            </div>
          
        </mat-drawer>
       
  </mat-sidenav>
  
    <mat-sidenav-content>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

<div class="check-side">
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="opened">
    <div class="brand">
      <img src="#" alt="logo">
  </div>

  <div class="content-sidenav-small">
    <a id="pagos" [routerLink]="'/dashboard'"><i id="icon" class="fi-rr-dollar"></i></a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id='certificados' [routerLink]="'/certificados'"><i id="icon" class="fi-rr-diploma"></i></a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a id='formularios' [routerLink]="'/formularios'"><i id="icon" class="fi-rr-form"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="logout">
    <a [routerLink]="'/login'"><i id="icon" class="fi-rr-sign-out"></i></a>
  </div>
  
</mat-checkbox>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var URL = window.location.pathname;
  console.log(URL);
  if(URL = '/dashboard'){
    $('#pagos').addClass("active");
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Creo que esto te ayudará: "breadcrumb angular" + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Angular ya resuelve eso con la directiva `RouterLinkActive` https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive según donde se navegue la directiva agrega las clases que se especifiquen para una ruta activa.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por sus comentarios lo pude resolver añadiendo a cada link un atributo que viene en angular que se llama Routerlinkactive y se usa de esta manera.

```
    <a [routerLink]="'URL'" routerLinkActive="active-link-small"
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"> Link </a>
```

Con sabes exactamente en que página te encuentras y podrás añadir estilos a la clase que se crea que es active-link-small espero le sirva a alguien más y muchísimas gracias a Lobos.